# shared_ptr implicit cast failing here and succeeding there?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have a class MemberBuilder that builds classes derived from Member for me, one of them being CommitteeMember. Member is a base class for a decorator pattern chain of objects that are instances of Member derived classes.

MemberBuilder contains the following method to create a CommitteeMember for me:

```
std::shared_ptr<CommitteeMember> MemberBuilder::createCommitteeMember(int memberID, int age, QString& name, QString& surName, Committee* committee)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<CommitteeMember> (new CommitteeMember(memberID,age,name,surName, committee));
}
```

in some method in the same MemberBuilder, it contains the following lines:

```
std::shared_ptr<Member> result;
result = createNormalMember(memberID, age, name, surName);
```

and then somewhere further down:

```
std::shared_ptr<Member> newChild = createCommitteeMember(memberID, age, name, surName, commission);
result->addChild(newChild);
```

this does not yield any compiler problems.

But if I create a std::shared_ptr mb in some class and then do:

```
std::shared_ptr<Member> member = getMember(memberID);

std::shared_ptr<Member> newChild = mb->createCommitteeMember(memberID, age, name, surName, commission);
member->addChild(newChild);
```

getMember has the following interface:

```
std::shared_ptr<Member> getMember(int memberID);
```

I get

```
"conversion from std::shared_ptr<CommitteeMember> to non-scalar type std::shared_ptr<Member> requested"
```

To me it seems I'm doing exactly the same, except that I call it from within the same class the first time. I can't understand why I'm getting an error the second time if it is accepted in MemberBuilder itself. What am I doing wrong the 2nd time that's not triggering an error the 1st time?
IIRC, if would do this with raw pointers, there would not be a problem.

Q: What difference makes it fail the 2nd time?

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you are working with different pointer types. `shared_ptr<CommitteeMember>` is not the same as `shared_ptr<Member>`. It's good that you cannot do this conversion, because the reference counts would not be shared and you'd end up with bizarre object lifetime behavour.

In order to statically cast a `shared_ptr`, look at `std::static_pointer_cast<>()`.

Comment: Although your answer answers why it fails the 2nd time, it does not explain the why it does not for the 1st. Can you explain that for me please?

Comment: Polymorphism and implicit derived-to-base conversion works with `shared_ptr`, right? Why would it be needed to manually cast then?

Comment: The most that `shared_ptr` can deal with polymorphism is to assign a `shared_ptr` a child class pointer (ie `shared_ptr<Shape> x(new Square);`. But `shared_ptr<Shape> sp = shared_ptr<Square>(new Square);` does not work. They are incompatible types. I think it would be theoretically possible for it to be implemented, but ... it's not. `static_pointer_cast` exists for this reason.